# how to show multiple locations with custom annotation in map view

Tags: ios, mkmapview

i have a dictionary having 4-5 locations,though it can vary.In need to show all these locations on the map view with different images.There is a start location and other location in dictionary.I have created the annotation for start point and end point.But not all the locations are seen on the map. Below is the code which i have tried.

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapViewer viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation{

static NSString *mapIdentifier=@"mapIdentifier";

MKAnnotationView *myAnnotation=[mapViewer dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:mapIdentifier];

if (myAnnotation == nil) {
    myAnnotation = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:mapIdentifier];
}
 CLLocationCoordinate2D parkCllocation=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([_tripDetails[@"park_lat"] doubleValue], [_tripDetails[@"park_long"] doubleValue]);

 CLLocationCoordinate2D orginCllocation=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([_tripDetails[@"origin_lat"] doubleValue], [_tripDetails[@"origin_long"] doubleValue]);

 CLLocationCoordinate2D location=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([loc[@"lat"] doubleValue], [loc[@"long"] doubleValue]);

if ((annotation.coordinate.latitude == parkCllocation.latitude)
               && (annotation.coordinate.longitude == parkCllocation.longitude))
{
    myAnnotation.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"pin1@2x.png"];
}

if ((annotation.coordinate.latitude == orginCllocation.latitude)
    && (annotation.coordinate.longitude == orginCllocation.longitude))
{
    myAnnotation.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"pin7@2x.png"];
}


if ((annotation.coordinate.latitude == location.latitude)
    && (annotation.coordinate.longitude == location.longitude))
{
    myAnnotation.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"pin4@2x.png"];
}
return myAnnotation
}
```

and this is the code from where i m getting the location,in loc dict i have stored the lat n long of location and then adding it to cllocationcoordinate2D,when i add this cllocationcoordinate2D in viewforannotation,and never goes inside

```
if ((annotation.coordinate.latitude == location.latitude)
        && (annotation.coordinate.longitude == location.longitude))
```

condition.

Plz help me out i m stuck up in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below code for multiple pins.

```
func dropPins(){
    var i = Int()
    var coord = CLLocationCoordinate2D()
    for i = 0 ; i < self.workLocationArray.count ; i++ {
        let lat = NSNumber(float:(self.workLocationArray.objectAtIndex(i).valueForKey("lat")!.floatValue)) as CLLocationDegrees
        let long = NSNumber(float:(self.workLocationArray.objectAtIndex(i).valueForKey("lng")!.floatValue)) as CLLocationDegrees
        let location = self.workLocationArray.objectAtIndex(i).valueForKey("client") as! String
        let title = self.workLocationArray.objectAtIndex(i).valueForKey("job") as! String
        coord.latitude = lat
        coord.longitude = long
        let locationq:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, long)
        let annotation = CustomPointAnnotation()
        annotation.coordinate = locationq
        annotation.title = title
        annotation.subtitle = location
        annotation.imageName = "ic_location"
        self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
    }
    var region = MKCoordinateRegion()
    region.center=coord;
    region.span.longitudeDelta=1 ;
    region.span.latitudeDelta=1;
    self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
}
```